# Flutter: problem with opening fb links in the application

Tags: android, flutter, facebook

I am a very beginner amateur, maybe my problem is trivial. I wrote an application that, among others displays facebook profile and get posts links. Links are open by LaunchUrl. So far it worked, suddenly, at the end of August, the links facebook.com/xxx/posts/xxx/ do not open (fb error: Sorry, something went wrong ...). Links are correct, they work in the browser. Are any permissions required that were not needed before?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.
Kac

Comment: provide some code which you tried.

Comment: please include your exact link you have test.

Comment: When did the problem happen ? After installing it on a real device or are you still in debug mode ?